# Play system click sound android java

Tags: java, android

I need to perform the sound of the click of the device (not custom one) . Ive tried making a fake click to obtain the sound but nothing so far , this is what i have.

```
fakeClick = new Button(this);
    fakeClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                
                fakeClick.playSoundEffect(0);
            }
        });
fakeClick.performClick();
```

The button gets clicked but not sound played. :(

Comment: Can you specific by saying play system click sound?

Comment: Im trying to make sound the click that the android device have , like the ringtone but click.